# Error uploading file from android sdcard

Tags: android

When uploading the file from my emulators sdcard to the local wampserver I got this error.

> 03-22 10:46:15.459: ERROR/Debug(487): error: localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused

sample code

```
String urlString = "http://localhost/uploads/index.php";

try
{
  //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName));
  // open a URL connection to the Servlet
  URL url = new URL(urlString);
```

Can anybody tell me what this error means and what I have to do to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely caused by the fact that the localhost name you are pointing at resides on the device and is **not** the host computer where the server is.

A way you could remedy this is to use the host pc's actual IP address.

Comment: i am running both the server and emulator in same pc and i also tried the ip addess which was mensioned by exception  127.0.0.1:80 in the browser and now i get that php page with this ip  but in emuator icant

Comment: @user664525 127.0.0.1 is the IP defined by localhost/loopback which will always refer to the local device unless aliased. You need to find the host PC's IP on the network.

Answer (score 1):

You must replace "localhost" with "10.0.2.2".

Comment: @Brice Favre: That's the Android testing IP, it redirects to the host computer's localhost. That's just how it is on the emulator.